# At what points do the numbers of Lucky Dice that can be gotten, change?

Tags: tiny-tinas-wonderlands

For instance, [Lucky Die #10 on this list of Queen's Gates'](https://www.ign.com/wikis/tiny-tinas-wonderlands/Lucky_Dice_-_Queen%27s_Gate) says that the other end of the broken bridge *might* be unlocked only after the Main Quest is complete, but is that true?

Is that the only point where the number of achievable Lucky Dice increases in an unexpected way?

Technically, you have to get hit a dialogue trigger to unlock punching on the Overworld to get the first visible Overworld Die near Snoring Valley, so that would count.

What doesn't count is just entering a new area, since if you run at the locations, then of course you can get the dice.